# Getting positional difference between two strings within the lists python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to find out the positional difference between two strings within two different lists. The code that I've been trying is..

```
a = ['ATG','TGA','CCC','GCT','TGA']

b = ['TCG','TGA','CCG','GCA','TGA']

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if j != b[i]:
       print i,j,b[i]
```

This code generates,,,

```
0 ATG TCG
2 CCC CCG
3 GCT GCA
```

I know how to get the difference between two lists, but my desired result is..

```
 ATG TCG TC*
 CCC CCG **G
 GCT GCA **A
```

Basically, I want to print out the positional differences between two strings within the lists. And I don't know where to start from, can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't understand your desired result. What are you trying to compute when you say "positional difference"?

Comment: hm I guess I wasn't good at explaining, I just want the difference between strings in list a and list b. So for example, the difference between 'ATG' in list a and 'TCG' in list b is TC.  *is for a common character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists and then iterate over them as a pair

Here the `tmp` variable uses a generator expression within a [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to check if the values are different. If they are not, then it will insert a `*`

```
>>> for i,j in zip(a,b):
...     tmp = ''.join(v if v!=i[k] else '*' for k,v in enumerate(j) )
...     if tmp!='***':
...           print i,j,tmp
... 
ATG TCG TC*
CCC CCG **G
GCT GCA **A
```

Comment: Great solution, Thanks a lot, I think I still have to study the list comprehension but this seems like a clean and concise solution.

Comment: Dear @Jessi It is an generator expression. You can read more more about that by reading [PEP-289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). All the best

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) can help here.

```
import itertools


a = ['ATG','TGA','CCC','GCT','TGA']
b = ['TCG','TGA','CCG','GCA','TGA']

for a_word, b_word in itertools.izip(a, b):
    output = ''
    for a_char, b_char in itertools.izip(a_word, b_word ):
        if a_char == b_char:
            output += '*'
        else:
            output += b_char
    print a_word, b_word, output
```